# Cannot Run WAR From Root Context in Karaf 2.2.0 OSGi Container

Tags: java, jetty, osgi, apache-karaf, pax

I have been struggling to get an web application to run in the root application context in Karaf 2.2.0 (it works fine in Karaf 2.1.4).  I have been able to isolate the issue to something easily duplicated using the Tomcat sample WAR.

1. Run the following command from Karaf:

   osgi:install -s webbundle:http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/appdev/sample/sample.war?Bundle-SymbolicName=tomcat-sample&Webapp-Context=/anything
2. Access the app from your web browser (http://localhost:8181/anything/index.html)
3. Uninstall the sample bundle
4. Reinstall the bundle using the root context path with the following command:

   osgi:install -s webbundle:http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/appdev/sample/sample.war?Bundle-SymbolicName=tomcat-sample&Webapp-Context=/
5. Attempt to access the app from your web browser (http://localhost:8181/index.html)
6. Note the 404 error.

Looking at the logs, it appears that when a web app is in the root application context, it prepends a "/default/" to any request.  For example, when trying to access /index.html it looks in /default/index.html, fails to find the page, and returns a not found error (see the log output below for more details).

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

---

LOG OUTPUT

```
15:14:46,270 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | REQUEST /index.html on org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$3@693a1324
15:14:46,270 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | ServerModel                      | eb.service.spi.model.ServerModel  268 | 52 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-spi - 1.0.1 | Matching [/index.html]...
15:14:46,270 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | ServerModel                      | eb.service.spi.model.ServerModel  292 | 52 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-spi - 1.0.1 | Path [/index.html] matched to {pattern=/.*,model=ResourceModel{id=org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ResourceModel-22,name=default,urlPatterns=[/],alias=/,servlet=ResourceServlet{context=/,alias=/,name=default},initParams={},context=ContextModel{id=org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.model.ContextModel-21,name=,httpContext=org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext@3942ef25,contextParams={webapp.context=}}}}
15:14:46,270 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | Got Session ID 17kb0ch4hv02w1ennfxju5owpw from cookie
15:14:46,270 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | sessionManager=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashSessionManager@7d8aecf1
15:14:46,271 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | session=null
15:14:46,271 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | servlet=default
15:14:46,271 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | servlet holder=
15:14:46,271 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | HttpServiceContext               | etty.internal.HttpServiceContext  115 | 54 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty - 1.0.1 | Handling request for [/index.html] using http context [org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.WebAppWebContainerContext@3942ef25]
15:14:46,271 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log                              | .eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog   70 | 43 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.2.2.v20101205 | chain=
15:14:46,272 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | WebAppWebContainerContext        | r.war.internal.WebAppHttpContext  113 | 64 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 1.0.1 | Searching bundle [tomcat-sample [97]] for resource [default/index.html], normalized to [default/index.html]
15:14:46,272 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | WebAppWebContainerContext        | r.war.internal.WebAppHttpContext  140 | 64 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 1.0.1 | Resource not found
15:14:46,273 | DEBUG | 30 - /index.html | log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has now been submitted as a Karaf Bug.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-577